# PyQt5 has error 'MainWindow' has no attribute 'exec_'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm new to using PyQT for a class project and I'm having some issues with it.

I want to launch MainWindow and to have 2 buttons to launch 2 separate dialog boxes (Dialog and subdialog); however I am getting the following error:

```
        sys.exit(mainwindowa.exec_())
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

Here is my code. I've tried playing around with how I write the exec_ function like writing it in the MainWindow class but I get the same errors and I'm pretty confuse on what to do

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
                             QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
                             QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
                             QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)

import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainwindowapp = QPushButton('Dialog')
        self.subwindowapp = QPushButton('CustomDialog')
        layout.addWidget(self.mainwindowapp)
        layout.addWidget(self.subwindowapp)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
        self.mainwindowapp.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):

        run = Dialog()
        run()
class Dialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(CustomDialog, self)

       

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel('e'))
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindowa = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(mainwindowa.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing an incorrect conclusion, you think that if the QDialog class has an exec_() method, so will other widgets like QMainWindow and that is not correct. QDialog creates an internal eventloop that other widgets do not, so in your case use the show() method and use the exec_() method of the QApplication:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindowa = MainWindow()
    mainwindowa.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer! it worked for me, thanks for all your help!